# Field value update in next field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am not sure, If there is a solution for the below requirement, Please help if is there.

I have two field in sharepoint list.

1) User name:(User & Groups)

2) Current Project: (Drop Down)(Ex-Contoso)

3) Deployed date: 1-1-2019 (Date and Time)

4) Existing client name:(It should automatic take the current project name if i change the value (From contoso to Microcraft) in current project status.

5) Exisiting deployed date: (As same as above if the Deployed date value will change then the existing date value should be taken the deployed date value)

Please help me on this.

Comment: Ganesh & Karthik, Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Do you want to allow your users to input the values in Existing client name and Existing deployed date columns? Or it will always be the copy of Current project and deployed date respectively.?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Yes, User will have access to to edit the exiting client name and exiting deployed date column .

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Trying to clear you here, If user is moving from one project to another project, we will edit the same. So the existing data should be reflect in another field.

Comment: Example: "A" is working in "Project1" from 1-1-2020 to 1-1-2021.So we have fields for this list is "User name,Current Project Name, From Date, To Date, Previous Project, Previous period from & previous period TO". Once "Project1" is finished, User assigned to other project "Project2" from 1-2-2021 to 1-2-2022. So we need to change the same in list, Once it is changed. The "Project1" should update in previous project field & From & To date should update it in previous period date. And the new change should update in Current project name & so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Example: "A" is working in "Project1" from 1-1-2020 to 1-1-2021.So we have fields for this list is "User name,Current Project Name, From Date, To Date, Previous Project, Previous period from & previous period TO". Once "Project1" is finished, User assigned to other project "Project2" from 1-2-2021 to 1-2-2022. So we need to change the same in list, Once it is changed. The "Project1" should update in previous project field & From & To date should update it in previous period date. And the new change should update in Current project name & so on.

So you can either use Workflow or Flow. If there are multiple projects, I would create a flow step where once the current assigned item status is completed, we get the current user in the flow then add that user to the next project based on the previous project value. You could try querying the list using call HTTP(workflow) loop through the list items which have the filter like User A assigned and status completed. From the results we pull the projects that are already assigned and finished, so that we don't assign finished projects as per the previously selected project which is completed.
Below are the workflow actions I would use,

Update list item- here you need to have end point with the previously mentioned filters)
Call HTTP
create a loop

On the other hand if you have access to Flow you can also try leverage the same there. Basically you get the idea of what needs to be done. This is a acheivable case, let me know if you need more details. I have layed out a logic which you can use.Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please help me to configure the flow sudheer ?

Comment: Sudheer, still it is not working for me after the workflow.

Comment: Sure.lets chat.

Comment: how to start chat..sudheer

Answer (score 0):

Create a Project list that has a single item for each project.  This list should have the ClientName and DeploymentDate columns.

Then, in a separate ProjectUser list, have your username column, and create a Lookup column to the Project list (this gives you a project drop-down).  In the column settings for the ProjectLookup column specify to show related fields ClientName and DeploymentDate from Project List.  Then any time the user chooses a project, the related values from the source Project list are displayed alongside it.